# How set custom font in a Webview in xamarin Android?

Tags: xamarin.android

```
 webViewOfferes = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webViewOffers);string start = "<html><head><meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html' charset='UTF-8' /><style  type='text/css'> li {line-height: 2;} @font-face {font-family: 'PlayfairDisplay-Regular';src: url('file:///Assets/fonts/PlayfairDisplay-Regular.ttf');} body{font-family:PlayfairDisplay-Regular;}</style></head><body>";
string end = "</body></html>";
webViewOfferes.LoadData(start + "<h3>My Custome Font:</h3>"+ end, "text/html", UTF32Encoding.ASCII.ToString());
                WebSettings Offersetting = webViewOfferes.Settings;
                Offersetting.DefaultFontSize = 13;
```

Not getting desired output with this code someone please help

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
file:///Assets/fonts/PlayfairDisplay-Regular.ttf
```

to

```
file:///android_asset/fonts/PlayfairDisplay-Regular.ttf
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for **both** Android and iOS.

After searching for a while I found the solution. Basically it's directly the same as you would write in HTML. So I created this HTML code in a HTML file, layed the font `myfont.otf` in the same folder and made this work:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style type=text/css>
            @font-face {
                font-family: 'CustomFont';
                src: url('myfont.otf')
            }
            body {
                font-family: 'CustomFont';
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>This is some sentence with a custom font.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now everything you have to do is:

Android:

- Put the font into the Android `Assets` folder
- Ensure its build action is `AndroidAsset`
- Pass the HTML string and the fontname (with path if in subfolder, like `Fonts/myfont.otf`) to the `WebView`

iOS:

- Put the font into the iOS `Resources` folder
- Ensure its build action is `BundleResource`
- Pass the HTML string and the fontname (with path if in subfolder, like `Fonts/myfont.otf`) to the `WebView`

I made a helper class for this:

```cs
public static class HtmlHelper
{
    public static string SurroundWithCustomFont(string htmlString, string fontPath)
    {
        return $@"
        <html>
            <head>
                <style type=text/css>
                    @font-face {{
                        font-family: 'CustomFont';
                        src: url('{fontPath}')
                    }}
                    body {{
                        font-family: 'CustomFont';
                    }}
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                {htmlString}
            </body>
        </html>";
    }
}
```